# How can I make a button which takes a picture, then sends it to another activity?

Tags: java, android

So I have an app with a button that opens the camera, takes a picture, and then shows it on screen. But I don't how to make it show up in a different activity. Help would be very much appreciated. I have had this problem for two weeks, and nothing I tried has worked.

Comment: This will definitely help you. https://stackoverflow.com/a/5991757/2470770

Comment: "I have had this problem for two weeks, and nothing I tried has worked." - Could you elaborate on this please? What have you tried and what hasn't worked?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd strongly suggest passing the image across the Intent as a file (unless it is very small, in which case you could send the bitmap as an extra with `intent.putExtra("data", bitmap)`).

This method, in your camera activity, saves the image to a file:

```
public void saveImageToFile(Bitmap bmp) {
    String fn = "sent_image";
    ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes);
    FileOutputStream fo = openFileOutput(fn, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    fo.write(bytes.toByteArray());
    fo.close();
}
```

Then use an intent to switch activities.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, YourSecondActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

In your other activity:

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(context.openFileInput("sent_image"));

ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.yourImageViewID);
iv.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

where `context` is either `this` or `getActivity()` in a fragment